# Kotlin type mismatch: required Array<Int?>? but found Array<Int>

Tags: kotlin, nullable, kotlin-null-safety

Here's my `Foo` data class definition

```
data class Foo(
    var fooArg: Array<Int?>? = null, 
)
```

And here's the call to it:

```
val bar: Array<Int> = arrayOf(1,2,3)
val foo = Foo(fooArg = bar)
```

But this gives an error `type mismatch: required Array<Int?>? but found Array<Int>`

I am confused, it is expecting a nullable type, and I provide it with a non-null value, how is that type mismatch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared `bar` as `Array<Int>`. Non-null types are not compatible with nullable types*. Change it to `Array<Int?>` and it will work:

```
val bar: Array<Int?> = arrayOf(1,2,3)
val foo = Foo(fooArg = bar)
```

Or alternatively:

```
val bar = arrayOf<Int?>(1, 2, 3)
```

*I think the correct thing to say is that arrays are invariant on the type parameter. But I get lost every time I try to understand it properly.

Comment: Got it. My bar is coming from another method which returns `Array<Int>` so I have to cast it, which is ugly but works. Thanks!

Comment: The real question is why do you want to allow null items in your array? 

Comment: It's generated code from `Jooq`...

Comment: “so I have to cast it” — Can you clarify that please? (I suspect you don't mean ‘cast’.)

Answer (score 3):

Adam's answer covers the solution, but it's also worth mentioning why what you're doing *doesn't* work. Java uses call-site variance annotations, unlike most other languages in existence. Kotlin takes the more traditional approach of using declaration-site variance annotations. That means that, when declaring a class which takes generic arguments, the writer of the class decides how it behaves with respect to subtypes.

Now, `Int` is a subtype of `Int?`. Namely, every `Int` is an `Int?`, but the reverse is not true. The question is: is `Array<Int>` a subtype of `Array<Int?>`? Well, covariant types such as `List<T>` preserve subtyping, so `List<Int>` is actually a subtype of `List<Int?>`. If you replace your example in the question with lists rather than arrays, everything works.

On the other hand, `Array<T>` is an invariant type. We can both read and write to an array, so it's never safe to upcast or downcast the type parameter. If we could, then the following would typecheck.

```
// Doesn't compile, for good reason
val myHealthyArray: Array<Int> = arrayOf(1);
val myScaryNullableArray: Array<Int?> = myHealthyArray;
myScaryNullableArray[0] = null;
```

Now my perfectly innocent `myHealthyArray` variable has a `null` in it that the type `Array<Int>` can't account for. That's contrary to everything Kotlin stands for, so it's disallowed on principle.

If you're only ever going to be using this data structure for *reading*, not writing, consider using `List<T>` or something covariant, which better describes the type of your function and also allows the subtyping relationships to work more fully.

Comment: Good effort typing into the void  ;) Marcin Moskala has a similar example and explanation: [Kotlin generic variance modifiers](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-generics-variance-modifiers-36b82c7caa39)

Comment: Another reference point is `MutableList`, which is invariant like `Array` (and unlike `List`).